# Get previous row value if current value in order clause differs from previous by particular value?

Tags: sql-server-2012

The example of the data:

```
part val
1   3.0
2   4.0
3   5.0
5   6.0
```

I need to obtain the previous row from column "val" if current value column "part" greater than previous by 1.

The example of the desired result:

```
part val val_lag1
1   3.0 NULL
2   4.0 3.0
3   5.0 4.0
5   6.0 NULL
```

By using LAG function I got this result:

```
part val val_lag1
1   3.0 NULL
2   4.0 3.0
3   5.0 4.0
5   6.0 5.0
```

I know that it can be done by joining table itself. But I wonder: is it possible to get the same result by LAG?

The script which I used to obtain examples:

```
SELECT  1 part, 3.0 val
INTO #t

INSERT INTO #t VALUES
(2, 4.0),
(3, 5.0),
(5, 6.0)

SELECT
    *,
    LAG(t.val, 1) OVER(ORDER BY t.part) val_lag1
FROM #t t

SELECT
    t.*,
    tt.val val_lag1
FROM #t t
LEFT JOIN #t tt ON t.part = tt.part + 1

DROP TABLE #t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  1 part, 3.0 val
INTO #t

INSERT INTO #t VALUES
(2, 4.0),
(3, 5.0),
(5, 6.0)

SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN t.part-LAG(t.part, 1) OVER(ORDER BY t.part)=1 
         THEN LAG(t.val, 1) OVER(ORDER BY t.part) 
         ELSE NULL 
    END AS val_lag1
FROM #t t

DROP TABLE #t
```